# Python Continuous Plotting?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, show

I am working with Python on a Raspberry Pi and I am plotting data that I would like to update within a loop continually. I have been using `plt.show()` but I need a command that will not pause the code, and preferably plot new data in the same figure while deleting the old data. Anything would help!!!

Here is an example of what I am doing as of now.

```
while True:
    i = 0
    while i < 128:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        s[i] = int(read_serial)
        i = i+1
    ref = np.linspace(0,127,128)
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(ref, s)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible using Matplotlib Animations. Here an example: https://pythonprogramming.net/live-graphs-matplotlib-tutorial/